# How to deal with null values - JPA/SQL/JPQL

Tags: sql, jpa, derby, jpql

should be simple one but i am currently really confused

i have a db query :

```
   public double markingAvg(Marking id) {
        System.out.println("In MarkingAvg");
        System.out.println("id = " + id);
        System.out.println("id = " + id.getId());
        Query m = em.createQuery("SELECT m.markSectionOne, m.markSectionTwo, m.markSectionThree, m.markSectionFour, m.markSectionFive, m.markSectionSix, m.markSectionSeven, m.markSectionEight, m.markSectionNine, m.markSectionTen, m.markSectionEleven, m.markSectionTwelve, m.markSectionThirteen FROM MARKING m WHERE m.id = :id", Double.class);
        m.setParameter("id", id.getId()); // Note the getId()
        System.out.println(m);


        List<Object[]> allMarks = m.getResultList();
        double total = 0.0;
        int count = 0;

        for (Object[] marks : allMarks) {
            for (Object mark : marks) {
                total += Double.parseDouble((String) mark);
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return total / (double) count;
    }
```

which just gets the values from the 13 columns and does the average on them, however it breaks when there is a null value in them, is there any way to say if there is a null value from any of the columns to return the total to be 0? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that if the value of the column is NULL it should be evaluated as 0, or you want the total be equal to 0 once one of the columns is NULL?

Comment: Ideally if a column is NULL it should be evalutaed as 0 however the total = 0 once a one column is null is also acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use inline conditional check for this:

```
    total += Double.parseDouble((String) ((mark==null) ? 0 : mark)));
```

Comment: i get the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String` but this looks like the solution i am after

Comment: total += Double.parseDouble((String) ((mark == null) ? "0" : mark));

Comment: My bad, I didn't take into account datatype conversions. String.valueOf(((mark == null) ? 0 : mark)) should work. Or, as you have already figured out, double quotations should work

Answer (score 1):

You could also handle this in your query: E.g.:

```
ij> CREATE TABLE T(I INT);
ij> INSERT INTO T VALUES 1, 2, 3, NULL;
4 rows inserted/updated/deleted
ij> SELECT * FROM T;
I          
-----------
1          
2          
3          
NULL       

4 rows selected
ij> SELECT (CASE WHEN I IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE I END) FROM T;
1          
-----------
1          
2          
3          
0          

4 rows selected
```

In your case it might be even better to calculate the average in SQL

```
ij> SELECT AVG(CAST(I AS DOUBLE)) AS AVERAGE FROM T;
AVERAGE                 
------------------------
2.0                     
WARNING 01003: Null values were eliminated from the argument of a column function.

1 row selected
```

Note the warning. If you actually want the NULLs to count as 0 in the average you have to use the CASE expression mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to the following:

```
SELECT NVL(m.markSectionOne,0), 
       NVL(m.markSectionTwo,0), 
       NVL(m.markSectionThree,0), 
       NVL(m.markSectionFour,0), 
       NVL(m.markSectionFive,0), 
       NVL(m.markSectionSix,0), 
       NVL(m.markSectionSeven,0),
       NVL(m.markSectionEight,0),
       NVL(m.markSectionNine,0), 
       NVL(m.markSectionTen,0),
       NVL(m.markSectionEleven,0), 
       NVL(m.markSectionTwelve,0),
       NVL(m.markSectionThirteen,0) 
FROM MARKING m WHERE m.id = :id;
```